# Selenium 2: getScreenshotAs() mixed up when running several tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, screenshot, webdriver

in a continuous integration build environment when running several Selenium tests in parallel (using Firefox driver) for different applications and each tests records its screenshots after every "action" (e.g. navigating to a page, submitting a form etc.) it seems like that whichever application window pops up that one gets on the top of the z-axis and will have the focus. 
So using the method getScreenshotAs() from the Selenium API to record images results in mixed up screenshots sometimes showing one application and sometimes the other application.
Recording the HTML responses with getPageSource() on the other hand seems to work correctly using the Firefox driver instance "bound" to the test.

Is there any solution how to deal with the mixed up image screenshots? Is there a possibility how to ensure that getScreenshotAs() only consideres its own Firefox driver instance? Thanks for any hints!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what flavor of selenium you are using but here is a reference to the API that looks like it would fix your problem, but I have never tested it.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

What that link shows is the IWrapDriver which according to the documentation Gets the IWebDriver used to find this element.

So from my understanding you could set your IWebDriver in your method and then wrapit with the IWrapDriver and then use that to reference for you getScreenShotAs();